# Windows 8 cannot access samba while other OS do

Tags: windows-8, unix, samba

I found some related topic, but they do not answer my problem or weren't enough accurate.

I have a samba on a ArchLinux machine (a rapberry), which can be accessed from Android and iOS apps but not from my Windows 8.1 laptop. It's not a Professional version.

Here is my `samba/smb.conf`

```
[global]
   workgroup = WORKGROUP
   server string = Raspberry Pi Samba Server
   netbios name = raspberryLIL0
   name resolve order = bcast host
   log file = /var/log/samba/%m.log
   max log size = 50
   security = user
;   wins support = yes
   map to guest = Bad User
   dns proxy = no
;   force user = olivier

[Home]
    comment = Home-Folder
    path = /toto
    valid users = olivier
    public = yes
    browseable = yes
    writable = yes
    guest ok = yes
    readonly = no
```

And I added the password for the user olivier with the command

```
smbpasswd -a olivier
```

Is it a new feature that Microsoft found *dangerous* like Ad-Hoc Networks ? Or is there something to do, that I missed ?

EDIT: I forgot to write down the error I get :

I go in the *Connect a Network Drive* (or something like that : it's in french for me =P)

I choose the folder `\\THE.IP.OF.MYRASP` and check the box for connecting with different credentials.

A popup shows up asking for my credential 3 times then I get (i didn't find it in english):

```
La connexion au lecteur réseau n'a as pu être créée car l'erreur suivante s'est produite:

Un périphériue attaché au système ne fonctionne pas correctement.
```

Thx guys !

Comment: I don't know why i cannot begin my post by **Hi there !** So I salute you from the end of the post !

Answer (score 0):

I see that your last option is `readonly` there might need to be an extra space: `read only = no`.
Maybe that is the problem.

Here are some other things you could try:

```
server role = standalone server
```

and/or

```
   usershare allow guests = yes
```

and/or add one or more of these to the [Home] section

```
   read only = no
   create mask = 0700
   directory mask = 0700
   valid users = %S
```

Comment: I tried your propositions, it still doesnt work. Since I can browse and read the files through other OS, I think I should do something on windows, don't I?

Comment: Connect the networkdrive `//THE.IP.OF.MYRASP/toto` works?  (note in your example you use `\\`s but that won't work.

Comment: It's worse ! I just followed the hint on windows which says to use \ instead of /

Comment: I don't think that's the problem

Comment: Sorry. Then I have no clues left.